# If this is checked jquery is not working in IE 9?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-9

Here am using a jquery checkbox click function and if i click a checkbox in IE 9  `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`  it is not throwing the alert message..but it is working in IE 10,firefox and chrome

```
if (isChildAvail == "true") 
{
    $(this).change(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("test");
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="divedit" class="editdiv"><p id="p_childlabel" class="childlabel">Children : ' + ChilAvailCount + '   </P><a class="childlabeledit">Edit</a></div>');
            $('.editdiv a').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
            EditForPullups();
         });
         }
  }
```

Any suggestion??

**EDIT:**

```
 $(this).change(function() {
```

The issue is with the Change function and not this one `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`

**EDIT(2):**

```
var strCheck = "";
$('.consumer-communication-checkbox').each(function () {

        strCheck = $(this).parent().text();


        if (strCheck.toLowerCase().indexOf("hugg") >= 0) {

            //scenario without child
            if (isChildAvail == "false") {
                jQuery(':checkbox').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
                        $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                        IsChildcontrolwithH = "1";
                        IsChildcontrolwithG = "0";
                        IsChildcontrolwithP = "0";
                    } else {
                        if (IsChildcontrolwithH == "1") {
                            $("#divpersonalrightheader").append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            //scenario with child
            else {
                if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
                    //Set SubscribedCode
                    SubscribedCode = "H";
                    $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="divedit" class="editdiv"><p id="p_childlabel" class="childlabel">Children : ' + ChilAvailCount + '   </P><a class="childlabeledit">Edit</a></div>');
                    $('.editdiv a').click(function () {
                        $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                        EditForH();
                    });
                }

                jQuery(':checkbox').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
                        $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="divedit" class="editdiv"><p id="p_childlabel" class="childlabel">Children : ' + ChilAvailCount + '   </P><a class="childlabeledit">Edit</a></div>');
                        $('.editdiv a').click(function () {
                            $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                            EditForH();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $("#divedit").remove();
                        if (IsChildcontrolwithH == "1") {
                            $("#divpersonalrightheader").append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                            IsChildcontrolwithH = "0";
                            IsChildcontrolwithG = "0";
                            IsChildcontrolwithP = "0";
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

**EDIT(3)**: Html content

```
   <div class="consumer-checkbox-wrap checked">
                <label class="consumer-communication-label checkbox" for="communication_11">
                    <input name="communication_11" class="consumer-communication-checkbox checkbox" id="communication_11"
                        type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true"><img src="Images/PMURP_Logos/hugg.jpg">
                s
                    <p>
                        Please send me communications, savings, and special offers from hugg® Communications
                    </p>
                </label>
                <input name="communication_11" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="http://www.hugg.com/email/12162011/SampleNewsletter.html"
                    target="_blank"><img src="../kcsso/images/Newsletter/hugg.jpg"></a>
</div>
 <div class="consumer-checkbox-wrap">
            <label class="consumer-communication-label checkbox" for="communication_13">
                <input name="communication_13" class="consumer-communication-checkbox checkbox" id="communication_13"
                    type="checkbox" value="true"><img src="Images/PMURP_Logos/scott.jpg">

                <p>
                    Please send me communications, savings, and special offers from scott® Communications</p>
            </label>
            <input name="communication_13" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="http://www.scott.com/email/11042011/samplenewsletter.html"
                target="_blank"><img src="../kcsso/images/Newsletter/scott.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. It would also help to see the HTML structure and which element `this` refers to.

Comment: what is `$(this)`? can you post an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: while loading the page it is throwing an error like this SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'live' 
id.min.js, line 1 character 2482

Comment: You have an extenal script 'id.min.js' that use 'live' method; it is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You have to update the script with its new version of change live to on (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Looks like a jQuery conflict or bad jQuery version with deprecated live function (deprecated in 1.7, removed in 1.9).... can you give us full details of what you are using? a fiddle example would be helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/E6RS9/

Comment: Fixed this issue...Object doesn't support property or method 'live' id.min.js...but it is still not working

Comment: @bala3569 hv you fixed it?

Comment: No the issue is with change function and not the other one

Comment: @bala3569 But your fiddle is working fine in IE9.

Comment: Ya it works for me too in IE9..but inn application it is not working

Comment: Could you post the HTML structure related to this script? That will help folks here to help you.

Comment: @jinmichaelr:Look at my EDIT 3

Comment: Do you have a live or demo address that could reproduce the issue? Edit3 still misses some element that are used by your jQuery code.

Comment: @Frederik.L No i cant expose the url since its against policy..can you tell me what you want??

Comment: @bala3569 As the question still fails to have a correct/accepted answer, it may be the lack the reproductibility, which is what I wanted to add here. If I create a Fiddle from the provided code in Edit2 and Edit3 : http://jsfiddle.net/p5cwF/ this won't reproduce the issue neither do any specific action. I think that a simplified version of your code that can actually reproduce the issue would lead to much better answers.

Answer (score 6):

The code you posted is missing a few closing brackets at the end, I'm not sure if you simply didn't copy/paste it all, or if it's missing and breaking your code:

This is what you posted (after tidying up indentation):

```
if (isChildAvail == "true") {
    $(this).change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("test");
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="divedit" class="editdiv"><p id="p_childlabel" class="childlabel">Children : ' + ChilAvailCount + '   </P><a class="childlabeledit">Edit</a></div>');
            $('.editdiv a').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                EditForPullups();
            });
        }
    }
```

It is missing the end of the change event handler **);** as well as the closing bracked for the if block **}**:

```
if (isChildAvail == "true") {
    $(this).change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert("test");
            $(this).parent().parent().append('<div id="divedit" class="editdiv"><p id="p_childlabel" class="childlabel">Children : ' + ChilAvailCount + '   </P><a class="childlabeledit">Edit</a></div>');
            $('.editdiv a').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().parent().append($("#divchildcontrol"));
                EditForPullups();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This (simplified) example works fine for me in IE9:
http://jsfiddle.net/rT2dT/1/

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

Alternatively, try

```
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

Which jQuery version are you using?

**EDIT:**
Following up on your 2nd edit from above:

I see that you are attaching event handlers in an `each` loop

```
$('.consumer-communication-checkbox').each(function () {
```

I assume that that selector will be on various checkboxes on your page. Inside that `each` look, you attach change handlers like so:

```
$(':checkbox').change(...
```

This selector will give you **all** the checkboxes on the entire page, not just the one in scope. In each iteration of the `each` loop you are attaching one of those event handlers to every checkbox on the page. Without knowing your HTML markup, I can't tell you what is happening exactly, but this will be the reason why everything works as expected in isolated examples (like as JSFiddle.net) and returns random results in context.

Comment: Look at my EDIT(2)..i have pasted the full code..this one is working in IE10,firefox,chrome and not working in IE 9

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`. Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like another library is overriding the `$` mechanics and leads to an undefined method call.

---

**UPDATED UPDATE:**

So this is the part that isn't working as expected:

```
//else {
    $("#divedit").remove();
    if (IsChildcontrolwithH == "1") {
        $("#divpersonalrightheader").append($("#divchildcontrol"));
        IsChildcontrolwithH = "0";
        IsChildcontrolwithG = "0";
        IsChildcontrolwithP = "0";
    }
//}
```

There is nothing wrong with it.

However, if either element with ID *divpersonalrightheader* or element with ID *divchildcontrol* doesn't exist at this point, this won't do anything. Off course, I assume that your logic stuff with `IsChildcontrolwith*` variables is correct. It may be a good idea to remove those variables in order to avoid dealing with many flag-like variables. If you need to put some data around an element, you can use `$(...).data()`.

Comment: Look at my EDIT(2)..i have pasted the full code..this one is working in IE10,firefox,chrome and not working in IE 9

Comment: What is the length of `jQuery(':checkbox')` in IE 9 ?

Comment: @bala3569 If it do has a length greater than zero (if not, change the selector for something more straight forward), try to `alert` something right after the change event (before any condition). Please describe what is happening at this point and provide some markup or a fiddle to reproduce the issue. I will investiguate on it this evening.

Comment: var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="communication_61"]:checked').length;
        alert(atLeastOneIsChecked);

Comment: i have tried it in IE 9..length is 1 since the code is inside document.ready() it is alerting as 1 during page load..but if i uncheck the checkbox it is not firing the change event

Comment: You mean that the issue is in the `else` part ?

Comment: Yes it is in else part

Comment: jQuery(':checkbox').change(function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {

Comment: This is confusing.. please look at my last comment on the question. The relevant code provided in the question should allow to reproduce the issue. If not, we get this kind of misleading answers because no one knows what's happening and guess stuff everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to UweB's answer that I upvoted. IE9 and other versions are very picky when it comes to the syntax while other browsers will dismiss certain stray commas or brackets depending on what they are.

Comment: Look at my EDIT(2)..i have pasted the full code..this one is working in IE10,firefox,chrome and not working in IE 9

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem using `is(":checked")` and `$.change` in IE9 since both are supported by jQuery version that you are using (and I think working on any version for this matter).

Since you did not provide the HTML structure you used, I created some assumptions based on the scripts in EDIT(2).

1. There are several checkboxes each with the class `consumer-communication-checkbox`
2. Each of these checkboxes are wrapped in a parent element. (I used `div` for my sample).
3. You are trying to bind change events on these checkboxes (either `isChildAvail` is true or false) but ONLY IF the parent container has a text containing "hugg".
4. You also want to do a logic for checkboxes that are checked when document loaded correctly and ready.

With those assumptions, I created simple code similar to yours: http://jsfiddle.net/9FtjU/3/

The HTML is coded based on my 1st and 2nd assumptions above. The JavaScript is just a simplified version of yours. In the script, I introduced the variable `isChildAvail`; you can vary the value of it replicate different results.

The issue could be that you were binding `change` event to all chekboxes.

I further simplified it (using my 3rd and 4th assumptions) to separate the change event from the iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/ub7kS/1/

I tested both jsfiddle links I provided above and both works in IE9.

===

On another issue, you might also want to check your click event handler for `$('.editdiv a')`

**UPDATE**

I edited the two jsfiddle links above.
This one's similar to your script: http://jsfiddle.net/hunLQ/
And this is the one with separated change event handler and iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/hunLQ/1/

Feel free to modify and use either as guide. Just change the `alert` with your logic.

Comment: Look at my EDIT 3 for HTML content

Comment: @bala3569 now, I don't get the point of checking whether the parent element has subtext "hugg". What should you check anyway?

Comment: @bala3569 check my updates, I basically used your html. I think my assumptions are close to yours that's why I the script I created works with too

Answer (score 1):

If it still doesn't work then you can trace your bug with jquery browser detect which is very easy way to find out whether any particular script is working fine in particular browser or not.

Code for detecting browser via Js/Jquery is below :

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1){ //your message comes here}

this code is only for Chrome browser you can define it for any(desktop, mobile, or tablet) of the browser